# Select dropdown list not updating when model is updated by another process

Tags: javascript, angularjs

I have a `select` list that is populated by an API that fills the array `vendors`.

```
<select ng-model="po.vendor" ng-options="vendor as vendor.VendorName for vendor in vendors"></select>
```

`po.vendor` is then updated via an API process downstream from that.  My problem is that the dropdown list is not updating to reflect the change.

**Controller:**

```
//fill the array so we can populate our dropdown list
$scope.vendors = $scope.vendors || [];
if ($scope.vendors.length < 1) loadExistingVendors();

//load some purchase order by id
getPurchaseOrderById(1);

function getPurchaseOrderById(purchaseOrderId) {
    apiService.getPurchaseOrderById(purchaseOrderId).then(function (data) {
        //apply po to the model
        applyPurchaseOrderModel(data);
    }, function (error) {
        //blah
    });
}

function applyPurchaseOrderModel(data) {
    //need to convert c# date to json data
    var regex = /-?\d+/;
    var match = regex.exec(data.dateRequested);
    var date = new Date(parseInt(match[0]));
    data.dateRequested = date;

    //set the po object to data, data.vendor contains selected vendor info
    $scope.po = data;
}
```

According to my `<pre></pre>` ouput of the model (`po.vendor`) and the array (`vendors`), I do see that they match.  But the select element is not updating to reflect this.  Why?

```
<h3>po.vendor</h3>
<pre>{{po.vendor | json}}</pre>
<h3>vendors array at the 6 position</h3>
<pre>{{vendors[6] | json}}</pre>
```

[Click here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/ZkVgT.png) for image of the `<pre>` output.

Comment: Where are you setting po.vendor?  You need to set it and I don't see anywhere that you do.

Comment: @DavidL In `applyPurchaseOrderModel`, there is `$scope.po = data` at the last line.  `data` contains a vendor object under data.vendor.

Comment: Are you certain that the "API process downstream" is updating the same in-memory instance of `vendor` that is referenced here by `po.vendor`?

Comment: @JC. Yes, I am certain.  I have several inputs elsewhere that point to the same object.  (i.e. `po.vendor.VendorName`, `po.vendor.Address`, etc. all get successfully updated and I do see the changes reflected in the inputs)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I think the `vendor` object in the `po` is not the same object reference that is in the `vendors` array. I do not believe ngOptions uses object equivalence logic. One way to fix it might be to find the matching `vendor` from the `vendors` array and attach it in place of the one on your `po` like so:

(Please forgive any blind coding errors)

```
function applyPurchaseOrderModel(data) {
    //need to convert c# date to json data
    var regex = /-?\d+/;
    var match = regex.exec(data.dateRequested);
    var date = new Date(parseInt(match[0]));
    data.dateRequested = date;

    //The fix
    for (var i=0; i<vendors.length; i++) {
        if (angular.equals(vendors[i], data.vendor)) {
            vendors[i] = data.vendor;
            break;
        }
    }

    //set the po object to data, data.vendor contains selected vendor info
    $scope.po = data;
}
```

Comment: I made a small edit here so that we're modifying the `vendors` array instead of the `po` object. Should still work, but less potential for side effects.

Answer (score 0):

The issue is that you are disconnecting `po` from the `$scope` watch when you overwrite it with a new `data` object. What you want to do instead is change all of its properties to a new value so they can be updated in the view during the next digest loop. To do so, replace the following:

```
$scope.po = data;
```

with

```
angular.extend($scope.po, data);
```

or, if you need a deep copy

```
angular.merge($scope.po, data);
```

Comment: Okay, I tried what you just said (btw, good to know) but it didn't help and the dropdown is still not updating.  Here is the $scope.po.vendor object *before* `angular.merge/extend`: https://i.imgur.com/eUYWrEk.png  And here it is *after*: https://i.imgur.com/sFZUA8e.png.